# Predefined Interface exposes some method,we are using that method but interface doent have definition part ,then how its working in c#?

Tags: c#

Interface exposes some method,we are using that method in class but interface doent have definition part ,then how its working in c#.
For Example

```
class ProductNameComparer : IComparer
{
   public int Compare(object x, object y)
   {
      Product first = (Product)x;
      Product second = (Product)y;
     return first.Name.CompareTo(second.Name);
   }
}
```

**Here `IComparer` exposes `CompareTo()` method, but `IComparer` doesn't have `CompareTo()` method definition part, then how its working?**

Comment: Interface don't have implementation, they are just contract....You have to define implemenation details in your class...

Comment: What are you asking here ? You question isn't clear at all

Comment: You need to give some more information, some code examples. It's hard to know what the question is.

Comment: What is the type of `first.Name`?

Comment: Interfaces cannot have method definitions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Interface` are simply contract which only declares method rather than having implementation part....`Class` which implements that particular `Interface` should have implemenation detail.

For instance, You have `IAnimal` interface and `Dog` is a class which implements `IAnimal` interface,

```
    public interface IAnimal
    {
        void Walk(); // Just declares the method, not implemenation
    }

    //Class implementing the interface 
    //must define the method specified in the interface
    class Dog : IAnimal
    {
        public void Walk()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dog can walk");
        }
    }
```

---

In your example, you misunderstood the `IComparer` interface.

`IComparer` defines an interface with a `Compare()` method

whereas

`CompareTo()` is declared by `IComparable`  interface.

In above code, you have implemented IComparer interface so, you are defining `Compare()` method details in your `ProductNameComparer` class.

Comment: Thanks.i misunderstood with compare and compareTo.

Answer (score 1):

An interface doesn't have any implementation, it's only a contract for how something should work.

You can't create an instance of an interface, you can only create instances of actual classes (or structs) that implement the interface. If you get a reference to an interface, it points to an actual object that implements the interface.

Any class that implements the interface has to implement all members of the interface, so if you have an actual object that fits the interface, you know that the method is implemented.

You can use an interface without any knowledge of any class that implements it, so you can write code that uses an interface even before there is any actual implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Here `IComparer` exposes `CompareTo()` method, but `IComparer` doesn't have `CompareTo()` method definition part, then how its working?

If this is your question that I think you are very much misunderstanding what is going and what "exposed" means.

Using your example:

```
class ProductNameComparer : IComparer
{
   public int Compare(object x, object y)
   {
      Product first = (Product)x;
      Product second = (Product)y;
      return first.Name.CompareTo(second.Name);
   }
}
```

Your `ProductNameComparer` class is implementing IComparer.  The requirement classes implementing `IComparer` is they contain a method with the signature `Compare(object x, object y)`.  This is the only thing that your `ProductNameComparer` is exposing.  That is nothing else.

Now you are using `CompareTo()` within the method, but you are not exposing it publicly.  It is difficult to explain in more detail without knowing the definition of `Product.Name`, but let's assume it is a string.

`System.String` implements `IComparable` (among other interfaces), so `string` has a `CompareTo()` method.  You are simply calling `String.CompareTo()` in your method, but nothing is exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces define the **contract** between types, they don't define the implementation, that's up to the classes implementing the `interface`.

Consider:

```
interface IWorkable
{
    void DoWork();
}
```

Then the implementation:

```
public class GoodWork : IWorkable
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        //add the implementation here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read a good c# tutorial before beginning to program..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners

Answer (score 0):

`CompareTo` method is not from `IComparer` but it is the method of your property `first.Name` which I suppose is a string.